# Session variable content and the back button

Tags: button, back

I'm on page 1 of a series of pages and save some data to Session. I now click a link on page 1 and go to page 2. I again save some data to the same Session variable. I do this several more times saving data to the same Session variable. I now click the back button several times returning to a previous page in the series. What data will exist in the Session variable? The data saved from the last page in the series or data from the page that I now sit on from using the back button.

Comment: which language are you using? show us your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data saved to the session stays in the session variable until you either remove it or the session expires. Back/forward/etc in the session doesn't affect the contents of the session variables - unless of course by loading a page you are changing the contents of those variables.

Comment: The comments below are incorrect. Pages accessed by the back button will display SESSION variable information that was captured at the time. I can confirm this, as a Coldfusion developer. The only exception is Mobile Safari, which acts as the comments suggest below. Most browsers do not make trips back to the server (data is retrieved from the cache) when pressing the back button. Mobile Safari does not obey this paradigm. I am currently trying to find a way around this. I will let you know, if I find a solution...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson: The question wasn't asking what would be "displayed" after the button was clicked, but what would be "stored" in the session variable (server side). The server side value won't change by clicking back, even if the browser continues to display cached old data in the client.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I think that is what I am saying in the previous comment, although this was posted 4 years ago...

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try: (assuming you use php)

**page1.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page1'] = 'from page1';

var_dump($_SESSION['page1']);
var_dump($_SESSION['page2']);
?>
<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>
```

**page2.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page2'] = 'from page2';

var_dump($_SESSION['page1']);
var_dump($_SESSION['page2']);
```

Go to page1, click link to page2, click back.
You will see that `$_SESSION['page2']` has the value still has the value you setted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about PHP - if so, then data saved in $_SESSION does not change upon pressing going to different page, since session data is kept on the server.
In short: you will always have last saved data in session, regardless of navigation.

Answer (score 0):

> What data will exist in the Session variable?

Whatever data you put there until either you overwrite it (or remove it) or the session expires.  Regardless of what the user does with their browser or how they move from one page to another, the session isn't controlled by the user/browser.  It's controlled by your server-side code.

If the user performs a request for Page 4 after having performed a request for Page 5 then what happens to the session values is entirely up to you.  If your code on Page 4 assumes that the user came from Page 3 and updates the session values to indicate being on Page 4, then the session values are updated.  If your code checks for a later state in the session values and retains that state, then the session values are not updated.

It's entirely up to you how you want this to work.